# How to determine which player won the game in TicTacToe?

Tags: java

I can't figure out how to check which player, X or O has won. I would apreciate any help that you can give me. I learned how to use the code here from a tutorial online from synforge.

XOButton:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class XOButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    ImageIcon X, O;
    byte value = 0;
    /*
     * 0:nothing 1:X 2:O
     */

    public XOButton() {
        X = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("X.png"));
        O = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("O.png"));
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {
        value++;
        value %= 3;
        switch (value) {
        case 0:
            setIcon(null);
            break;
        case 1:
            setIcon(X);
            break;
        case 2:
            setIcon(O);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

TicTacToe:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class TicTacToe extends JFrame {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    XOButton buttons[] = new XOButton[9];

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TicTacToe();
    }

    public TicTacToe() {
        super("TicTacToe");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new XOButton();
            p.add(buttons[i]);
        }
        add(p);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not invest 5 seconds to properly format your code, but expect us to invest some time to read and understand all of this without any kind of documentation / explanation / comments? That is kind of rude.

Comment: I format my code this way to make it easier for myself to understand. Sorry.

Comment: Ever heared of [Coding](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) [Conventions](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html)?

Comment: @Turing85 Although I agree that questions on SO should have well formatted code, keep in mind that not all of us have been in the field for as long as others. Instead of calling people out on what they've done, provide guidance on what they should do to improve their abilities. Personally, I had terrible formatting practices when I started software development, but you improve with experience.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to check all 8 winning positions after each turn- 3 horizontal, 3 vertical, and 2 diagonal.

Maybe provide a getter method for the XOButton, to be called in a method in the TicTacToe class?
This can then be triggered in the buttons' actionlistener.

Comment: can you start me off? I am still a little bit new. sorry.

Comment: You have an array of XOButtons, in order, right? What if you add a method to your XOButton class to `return value;`? What if you check to see if any row of non-zero values are identical after every move? Hint: what code is run every time a button is pressed?

Comment: @MrRubiksMinecraft If you are new to Java, I would recommend some [basic tutorials about Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) instead of a GUI application. For example, your buttons would be easier to handle if you were using a two-dimensional array.

Comment: how do i get the XOButtons out of the gridlayout while the app is running to check their value?

Comment: The gridlayout doesn't *contain* the button, it just holds a reference to it (them). Your XOButtons are still perfectly accessible in the array `buttons`.

Comment: where would i put the part of my code that checks the buttons for the value using the method that i make in XOButton class

Comment: @MrRubiksMinecraft Choose any place where you can access the array.

Comment: `if(buttons[0].getValue()==1&&buttons[1].getValue()==1&&       buttons[2].getValue()==1)
  {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"X Wins!"); }`                                                                                                                                                                                     is this good?

Comment: That works, if you feel like writing 16 statements. If you want to make it a bit quicker, you can put that in a method (gets 3 ints in parameters, let's call them a, b, and c) that does essentially what you just wrote, but uses buttons[a] instead of buttons[0], and so on. You can then call the method in rapid succession with the different parameters (make sure to design the program to only display the JOptionPane once- sometimes, a player might win in more ways than one, and you don't want to show the JOptionPane 2 or 3 times in a row)